# React native: async, await, fetch

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, fetch-api

In my app, I'd like to perform an HTTP request, wait for the request to be completed, and show the result

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation, route }) {

....

console.log("Try to decode");

const result = GeocodingUtils.getAdressFromCoordinates(myLocation);

console.log("Get Address OK");

<Text>{result}</Text>
```

And this is my getAdressFromCoordinates method

```
export default class GeocodingUtils {

static async getAdressFromCoordinates(location) {

    try {
        const response = await fetch("valid_url");
        const responseJson = await response.json();

        .....

        console.log(street + " " + streetNumber);

        return street + " " + streetNumber;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I taught that the console output would have been something like:

**Try to decode**

**St. Mary street**

**Get Address OK**

but that's the true output:

**Try to decode**

**Get Address OK**

**/*print a promise object*/**

So I have two problems:

the first one is that my geocode function should "stop" the code flow execution until its end
the second is that I'd like to print the result of my funciont in a Text component

Ty in advance

Comment: You need to use an [effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you 're having is that you 're calling an async method and not waiting for it to respond before storing it in the result const.

That's why you 're getting a Promise back.

try this :

```
let result;
GeocodingUtils.getAdressFromCoordinates(myLocation).then(r => result = r);
```

or even better define your function as async:

```
var HomeScreen = async({ navigation, route }) => {

....

console.log("Try to decode");

const result = await GeocodingUtils.getAdressFromCoordinates(myLocation);

console.log("Get Address OK");

<Text>{result}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found is to use the useEffect hook, like
kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze said.

```
useEffect(() => {

    (async () => {

        ....

        let addressString = await GeocodingUtils.getAdressFromCoordinates(
            latitude, longitude
        );

    })();
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to `await` the `GeocodingUtils.getAdressFromCoordinates` result:

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation, route }) {

....

console.log("Try to decode");

const result = await GeocodingUtils.getAdressFromCoordinates(myLocation);

console.log("Get Address OK");

<Text>{result}</Text>
```

You can also use promises:

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation, route }) {

....

console.log("Try to decode");

GeocodingUtils.getAdressFromCoordinates(myLocation).then(function(result){
console.log("Get Address OK")
<Text>{result}</Text>
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution leads to the following error

TransformError SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (44:23)

Comment: I have added another way to wait for the result, using a Promises based syntax, you can try this one if your version of js doesn't support async/await.